# How to delay sending activation email in django_registration?

Tags: django, backend, django-registration, django-paypal

I am integrating django_paypal with my django_registration setup for which I have created a custom backend. I can't seem to find in the code where it sends the activation email. Is this located in the backend?

I want to wait and send the activation email until after they have completed a paypal checkout and I receive the IPN notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user` manager method has a `send_email` parameter, which defaults to `True`.

You just need to set `send_email=False` when you create a new user.

```
new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                            password, site,
                                                            send_email=False)
```